Valid ways to ask 'what age / how old' questions with 'の時'
みんなさんお疲れ様でした！
I'm working through the workbook questions in Genki II for chapter 20, specifically the か and かどうか constructions for embedding questions in sentences.
One of the questions is as follows:
I want to know how old I will be when I get married.
My answer:
結婚するの時、何歳か知りたいです
The provided answer:
何歳の時、結婚するか知りたいです
I'm just wondering whether my answer is a grammatical and/or natural way to phrase this sentence?
The provided answer makes sense in hindsight but kind of breaks my English-speaking brain ("At the time of what age, when getting married, I want to know" vs "At the time of getting married, what age, I want to know").
Thank you in advance!

The provided answer: 何歳の時、結婚するか知りたいです -- I would say 何歳で結婚するか・・

Your approach seems to be closer to the original Japanese. The provided answer is structurally closer to "I want to know at what age I will marry".
However, your attempt is not error-free, either. The correct version would be:

I want to know how old I will be when I get married.

結婚した時、(自分が)何歳(なの)か知りたいです。
結婚した時、何歳になっている(の)か知りたいです。



It's far more natural to say した時 rather than する時. This type of た-form expresses perfective aspect. I think your textbook has an example similar to 駅に着いたときに電話してください. Also note that するの時 is always ungrammatical. Japanese relative clauses never use の between the verb and the noun.
The explanatory-の is technically optional, but it makes the sentence sound more natural.

What if you used present/future tense?

結婚するとき、何歳になるのか知りたいです。
I want to know what age I will turn when I get married.

This is grammatical but sounds unnatural because it implies that getting married is the cause of getting old, as if the speaker didn't know people get older regardless of their marriage status.

Thanks for your answer and the many important nuances you've highlighted!
